# Assigning a numerical value to each alphabet in corresponding order and then summing any inputted word

Tags: python, beginner

I made a function that outputs the sum of the value of each letter in a word. For example if I input hello my function would output 52.

```
def words_to_marks(s):
    import string
    values = {}             # dictionary to store value of each alphabet
    values_of_words = []    # to store final value of words
    for index, letters in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1):     # creates the dictionary
        values[letters] = index
    final = []              # stores value of each number before adding
    for letter in s:
        letter_lower = letter.lower
        final.append(values[letter])    # appends the value of each letter into the list
    values_of_words.append(sum(final))  # sums all the values in the list
    submit = str(values_of_words)       # converts into string so I can remove the brackets around the list
    return submit[1:-1]


test = words_to_marks("friends")       
print(test)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction for how I should condense or improve my code.

Comment: Hello, you'll need to explain in your post how you map a letter to its numerical value, because there are a gazillion ways to do this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, the initial `words_to_marks` function is full of "anti-patterns/bad smells".

When reviewing in steps:

- instead of iterating over `string.ascii_lowercase` and generating/filling a dictionary of letter indices on **each** function call with:

  ```
  for index, letters in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1):     # creates the dictionary
      values[letters] = index
  ```

  create a predefined top-level dict `lowercase_indices_map` at once:

  ```
  import string

  lowercase_indices_map = {c:i for i, c in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}
  ```
- converting each letter of the word with:

  ```
  for letter in s:
     letter_lower = letter.lower
  ```

  is completely redundant as the whole word can be *lowercased* at once `s = s.lower()`
- and the *"magic"* like:

  ```
  values_of_words.append(sum(final))  # sums all the values in the list
  submit = str(values_of_words)       # converts into string so I can remove the brackets around the list
  return submit[1:-1]
  ```

  is just an unnecessary thing that you should avoid doing in future. The sum of letter indices is simply calculated with a single `sum(...)` call.

---

The whole idea fits in few lines of code:

```
import string

lowercase_indices_map = {c:i for i, c in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}

def sum_letters_indices(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return sum(lowercase_indices_map[char] for char in word)
```

Sample usage:

```
print(sum_letters_indices("hello"))    # 52
print(sum_letters_indices("friends"))  # 75
```